# Why I get segfault in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, page-fault

I reserved a block of memory for my driver in dts:

```
<pre>

    reserved-memory {
        #size-cells = <2>;
        #address-cells = <2>;
        ranges;

        adc_reserved: ADC {
            compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
            reg = <0x5 0x0 0x0 0x100000>;
            /* memory at pysical adress 0x500000000 actually exists and */
            /* I need exactly this region */
        };
    };
    ...
    my_device {
        ...
        memory-region = &lt&adc_reserved>;
    };

</pre>
```

Then in my driver I did the following:

```c
/* Allocate memory */
dma_set_coherent_mask(dev, DMA_BIT_MASK(64));
dma_vaddr = dma_alloc_coherent(dev, dma_size, &dma_paddr, GFP_KERNEL);
dev_info(dev, "Allocated coherent memory, vaddr: 0x%0llX, paddr: 0x%0llX\n",        (uint64_t)dma_vaddr, (uint64_t)dma_paddr);
```

In log I see this:

> Allocated coherent memory, vaddr: 0xFFFFFF800CB00000, paddr: 0x500000000

Everething seems ok. Then I get page struct:

```c
struct page* p = vmalloc_to_page(dma_vaddr);
```

and then segfault when I access any member of p:

> Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffffbf11800000

- Why I get segfault?
- How can I get valid pointer to page in my case?

Comment: Did you check if the value of p is NULL?

Comment: p is ffffffbf11800000

Comment: Means that would be the address in the page table for that page, but no page table entry has been created.

Comment: My guess is you need to populate using something like https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/mm/sparse-vmemmap.c#L211 but I don't know the memory mgmt stuff very well.  Normally the kernel gets the memory map handed off from the boot firmware.